# why did this simple jquery code refused to work

Tags: jquery

This code look very ok to me. But it just didn't work. Can anyone tell me why?

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    $('myButton').click(function() {

        alert(i);

    });
}
```

The thing is that nothing happened in my browser at all. Not even an error was shown by the developer tools.

Comment: no class or id prefix for class use `.` like `$('.myButton')` for id use `#` like `$('#myButton')`

Comment: The `for` loop is redundant too - you'll see `5` alerted 5 times. If you actually want to `alert()` 5 different values, you'll need a closure

Comment: why you want to alert 5 times on single click.?

Comment: it worked for me, as @guradio said you just should add "#" if is an id or "." if is a class on $('myButton').

Comment: is it inside **$(document).ready()** ?

Comment: All you're doing there is to set the click event of a button 5 times. Of course nothing happens in the UI because you haven't actually done anything yet.
If you want to actually see the alert then you have to click the button. Maybe you can explain exactly what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @gurado now i see my fault. its really that selector prefix. thanks a lot.Guess its been a while i did some coding  on jquery

Comment: @pedroyanky glad it works happy coding :)

Comment: you miss the important part in coding. the `( . )` for class and `( # )` for the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is , you did not mention `.` for class, or `#` for id in jquery line:
 `$('myButton').click(function()` 
***use  prefix . for class attribute and # for id attribute.***

now i fixed it, `$('.myButton').click(function()`, nd here i created form nd apply function on it.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    $('.myButton').click(function() {

        alert(i);

    });
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="myButton">Click Me!</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

if you want to alert single time , i modified code and here is [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/yashsoni789/Lpvu5qd2/2/) too. 
 if you can not see alert still, then restrart browser. 
if you want to alert 5 times like number 1,2,3,4,5 then use this :[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/yashsoni789/0kfqmaq6/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use selector in proper way. I'm trying to give some example.

**For Class:**

```
    <button class="myButton"></button>
    $('.myButton').click(function() {
          alert(i);
    });
   // Dot (.) is using for class in selector
```

**For ID:**

```
    <button id="myButton"></button>
    $('#myButton').click(function() {
          alert(i);
    });
   // Dot (#) is using for class in selector
```

**For Selecting the element by name:**

```
       <button></button>
        $('button').click(function() {
              alert(i);
        });
```

You can also select the element by element name, but it is not recommended because it will be apply to all buttons more than in the same page. I hope this will be help for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button type="button" class="myButton">Click Me!</button>


$('.myButton').click(function() {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                alert(i);
        }
    });
```